# Apache Commons FileUpload without HTML Form

Tags: java, upload, ftp

IS it possible to use Apache Commons FileUpload without requiring the HTML form?

I'm trying to upload a single specific file each time and uploading through my Java application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind giving us more details on your requirements and environment (Sever, client, personal server, corporate machine,...)?
Are you allowed to set up a socket connection on the server?
You tagged your question with "FTP". Is a FTP upload a feasible solution?

If you use FTP(S)/SFTP you could go for [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/).

#### Edit

The requirement for an HTML form depends on the server side: If the server expects a file upload on the basis of the HTTP protocol (ie [HTTP 1.x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)) then you must submit a proper HTML form.

Hint: In HTML 4.x it required some client programming to have a progressbar in a file upload. With HTML 5 I am not (yet) an expert.

Keep us posted on your progress/success.

Comment: Ofcourse.  Yes it would be a client and FTP is a feasible solution - but then i'd consider SFTP? I can't set up a socket connection on the server though.

Comment: Depending on your requirements you should rather go for a secured connection (SFTP). You can ask google which FTP libraries are out there. There might be some difficulty in creating the secured connection with SSL certificate w/o allowing man-in-the-middle attacks (but this is anohter topic.)

Comment: I'm building an application in increments, and for my next increment I was hoping to upload multiple files with a progresws bar.  The Apache Commons FileUpload seems perfect for my future increments - is it not possible to use it without requiring the HTML form?  I've already tried SFTP with JSch.